# only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices problem

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

when running this code I have an error

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

python code

```
import random

def getsys():
    row = ''
    for i in range(0 , 8):
        randintt = str(random.randint(0 , 4))
        row += randintt
    return row


def getx():
    x = []
    for i in range(0,14):
        mysys = getsys()
        x.append(mysys)

    return x 

y = getx()
print (y)
```

---

```
import initialsys
import numpy as np

R = np.array([[0.90 , 0.93,0.91 , 0.95],
               [0.95 , 0.94, 0.93, 0],
               [0.85 , 0.90 , 0.87 , 0.92],
               [0.83 , 0.87 , 0.85 , 0 ],
               [0.94 , 0.93 , 0.95 , 0],
               [0.99 , 0.98 , 0.97 , 0.96],
               [0.91 , 0.92 , 0.94 , 0],
               [0.81 , 0.90 , 0.91 , 0],
               [0.97 , 0.99 , 0.96 , 0.91],
               [0.83 , 0.85 , 0.90 , 0],
               [0.94 , 0.95 , 0.96 , 0],
               [0.79 , 0.82 , 0.85 , 0.90],
               [0.98 , 0.99 , 0.97 , 0],
               [0.85 , 0.92 , 0.95 , 0.99]
              ])

def expression(r ,possition , char ):
    exp = 1-r[possition , char]


x = initialsys.getx()
possition = 1
Total = 1
char = ""
for row in x :
    for char in row :
        if char!= 0 :
            exp = expression(R , possition , char)
            Total = Total*exp
    Total = 1-Total
    possition = possition + 1
```

Comment: FYI this is besides the point but you should use `np.array()` over `np.matrix()` always. Matrix is deprecated. Also, you are ALWAYS going to get 0 even if this worked correctly; `int()` of any value between 0 and 1 will be truncated to 0. How do you expect to index the matrix with an int (possition) and a character (charr)?

Comment: sorry, edited the code but  that error currently appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people who are getting this error while doing machine learning coding using numpy. When you are trying to print out the prediction `classes[d["Y_prediction_test"][0,index]]` you will be getting the same error. Please note that `d["Y_prediction_test"][0,index]` return a `float` like 1.0. so you should convert it to `int`

```
plt.show()
val = d["Y_prediction_test"][0,index]
val = int(val)
print(classes[val])
```

I have looked for this answer. But was not able to find it. It took some time to solve this, I hope this will help you. I'm self-learning ML/AI. So if we are in the same team, let's connect and help each.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems in your code but to fix your current error you need to index the array with integers as said in the error and not a char, you could do `int(char)` and then return the result.

```py
def expression(r, possition , char):
   return 1-r[possition, int(char)]
```